# Copy template file only shared directory is present + Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have almost achieved in orchestrating my system with ansible. Except one thing.

I have a template files called

```
  -  database.yml
  -  secrets.yml
```

For example purpose I have `database.yml` content look like this.

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: 5


{{ passenger_app_env }}:
  <<: *default
  database: {{ db_name }}
  username: {{ db_user }}
  password: {{ db_password }}
```

Now, I need to copy this template to a shared directory on server. But with a conditions that the shared directory exist.

```
  - name: 'Template copy'
    become: yes
    become_user: '{{ deploy_user }}'
    template:
      src: '{{ item }}'
      dest: '/home/deployer/template'
      with_items:
        - database.yml
        - secrets.yml
```

Now, I have 2 problem with this.

1. `with_items` - > Does not work with tempalte.
2. How do I check for conditions (that if the shared directory is present than copy the template)

Note: I have all the variable defined in `vars/main.yml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`with_items` is definitely working with templates. your identation seems a bit off, it should look like :

```
 - name: Template copy
   become: yes
   become_user: '{{ deploy_user }}'
   template:
     src: '{{ item }}'
     dest: '/home/deployer/template'
   with_items:
     - database.yml
     - secrets.yml
```

And for the second part of the question, you could use ansibles [stat](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/stat_module.html) to determine if the shared directory exists and then deploy the template

```
- name: check for shared dir
  stat:
    path: /path/to/shared/dir
  register: shared_dir

- name: Template copy
  when: shared_dir.stat.exists
  ...
```